# Is there a javascript equivalent to what Opera speed dial does?

Tags: javascript, web, download, opera

Opera speed dial has a very [nice way to retrieve sites big icons](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-speed-dial-enhancements/), were they to exist. Is there any javascript library that could provide me the equivalent feature ?

Comment: A client side library? To run on a regular web page? To access arbitrary third party websites?

Comment: You mean retrieve `<link rel="icon" href=.... >` or take a snapshot of the page? You will be better doing it server side anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a normal web browser, you'll need some kind of server-side mechanism.  Origin restrictions prevent your code from accessing content on other domains.

To get icons that a page specifies (`<link rel="icon">`), you'll need to download and parse the HTML.  [htmlparser](https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser) can do that for you.

To generate the screenshots of pages that don't specify a `<link rel="icon">`, that *must* be done on a server.  There is no API that allows you to take an actual screenshot of a page (although there are [workarounds](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)), and even if there was, you'd still be subject to Origin restrictions.

To generate screenshots on a server, [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is your best bet.  It's a headless WebKit engine with a JS API; it's [easy](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) to generate screenshots.